# With ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers, How to get BodyTagHelper to run last?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I've got several tag helpers on a page that accumulate information that I want to output at the end of the html body.  This means that those tag helper that are not the BodyTagHelper must run before the BodyTagHelper runs.

I know how to change the order of multiple tag helpers running on the same element but not how to change the actual order of the tag helpers processed on the page.  How can I make a tag helper run last?

That is, I can set the order of my body tag helper as follows but the other tag helpers are still running after this.

```
public class BodyTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override int Order => int.MaxValue - 100;
```

Comment: Are all the tag helper on the same tag? iirc the `Order` property is only there to determine the order the execution when more then one tag helper is placed on the **same** tag. Otherwise I think the tag helpers are executed in the order of their appearance in the razor template. So your tag would need to appear last inside the template but considering its the body-tag, that's hardly possible

Comment: Well thinking about it, it may be possible if you do the content rendering within your tag helper. So your renderer will read the content of the body tag completely, then parse this content via the razor engine and put finished content (that should be rendered to a string) into your tag as content again. Dunno if you could enter access the other tag helpers content with it though.